# Film/Miniseries where a man explodes a melon by psychokinesis

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I have been looking for this film/series for years so any help is greatly appreciated!

It was played on TV in the '90s, and I can only recall one specific scene: A man was standing behind a small concrete divider and a melon or watermelon was on the other side. He focused his energy, made a movement as if he was about to punch the wall (he didn't touch it), and then the melon exploded on the other side.

The film or TV series was set in the future and had an industrial post-apocalyptic theme, similar to Barb Wire.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F Stack Exchange! Could you tell us a little more? For example, what did the man look like?

Comment: Thanks, I'm afraid I dont remember the details of the man enough to add any specifics. I do remember the main protagonists seem to be a male and female throughout the show. I didnt get to watch the entire show as my dad turned the tv off before bed time. So the exploding melon scene is the only thing i remember enough to describe.

Comment: A male and a female, broadcasted in the 90's.. sounds like X-Files, but that wasn't set in the future. Can we rule out X-Files?

Comment: This is for sure an obscure mini-series or lower budget film, it wont be any of the big sci-fi titles as I'm pretty into sci-fi. So yes X-Files can be ruled out. 

The style of the film was along the lines of Running man meets Barb Wire in an industrial post apocalytic Earth.

Comment: I just remembered one more thing about the environment of this scene, it was underground. 

I also remembered some of the other scenes were very industrial (pipes everywhere) like a power plant.

Comment: I guess this is too obscure for anyone to remember :(

Comment: Shadoevision had a scene like that. The scene involved a tomato, though.

Comment: I was looking for the same answer. I belive the white guy was fighting an older very buff Asian guy. There is a scene where a guy kills the Asian guy by punching a door that he is holding closed during a fight scene. I feel like the movie was definitely set in the future in a city where crime had taken over.

Comment: Sounds like _Scanners_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is *[TC 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TC_2000_(film))* with Billy Blanks and Bolo Yeung.

> Jason Storm (Blanks) and Zoey Kinsella (Phillips) are two cops under the leadership of The Controller, whose task it is to contain the vicious thugs and roving gangs that terrorize the otherwise unprotected community.
>
> When Zoey is murdered by the notorious Niki Picasso (Jalal Merhi), The Controller converts her body into a cybernetic killing machine that is unleashed upon the gangs without mercy. But Jason knows too much, and eventually must battle impossible odds as he takes on the gangs, The Controller, and the seemingly unbeatable Zoey in a race to save the Earth’s atmosphere from nuclear destruction. This fast-paced chiller boasts furious fight sequences featuring Matthias Hues and legendary martial arts star Bolo Yeung.”

[image: Screenshots]

The melon scene:

Comment: Can you offer a screenshot or some evidence that this is the right answer?

Comment: https://youtu.be/yHmxPhbAY34?t=3m27s looks to depict Bolo Yeung breaking a melon through some sort of remote martial art technique.

Comment: https://youtu.be/B7mDljHbroQ

Comment: Thanks! I only joined to answer this question once I had figured it out. Glad to know I was not the only one thinking about this movie.

Comment: @user71032 - We have lots of unanswered movie-ID questions if you feel like answering some more :-)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is absolutely the correct film! I wasnt sure at first but as soon as I started watching it there are so many elements that it just had to be this movie. This film has eluded me for 19 years!

Comment: Very welcome! Glad to help.